# 2хсторонняя передача файла NIO.2

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы, nio2

у меня есть код передачи от сервера -> клиенту, и наоборот. По отдельности все работает нормально, но я хочу сделать 2х сторонюю передачу.

Я руководствовался логикой такой. передача файла и его получение, 2 левых потока. Код получения файла в вечный цыкл. Передача файла (хотел запустить поток и остановить, и если пользователь нажимает на соответствующую кнопку где открывается окно с выбором файла, поток пробуждается и после того как файл будет отправлен - поставить поток на паузу, и с новым вызовом будить его.)
После того как я попытался сделать 2ю передачу, у меня дублировался код и был занят канал.

Подскажите, как правильно это сделать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно каналы использовать и в многопоточной среде, только разносить по отдельным потокам надо не приём и передачу, а обработку каждого нового подключения:

```
public class ExecutorNioServer {
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "received_%d.jpg";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ExecutorService executor = null;
        try {
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

            try (ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()) {
                serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
                while (true) {
                    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                    executor.execute(() -> {
                        String fileName = String.format(FILE_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis());
                        try (FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(fileName),
                                                                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                             socketChannel) {
                            fileChannel.transferFrom(socketChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                        }
                        catch (IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (executor != null)
                executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Но более интересный и естественный для каналов вариант - это не потоки, а асинхронность:

```
public class SelectorNioServer {
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "received_%d.jpg";

    private static class Storage {
        private final AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel;
        private Future<Integer> writeOperaion;
        private long position;

        public Storage() throws IOException {
            String fileName = String.format(FILE_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis());
            fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get(fileName),
                                                       StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                       StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        }

        public void write(ByteBuffer buffer) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            try {
                if (writeOperaion != null)
                    position += writeOperaion.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                writeOperaion = fileChannel.write(buffer, position);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException exc) {
                close();
                System.err.println("Write timeout");
            }
        }

        public void close() {
            try {
                fileChannel.close();
            }
            catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        try (ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()) {
            serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            while (true) {
                selector.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = keys.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = iterator.next();

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, new Storage());
                    }

                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        Storage storage = (Storage) key.attachment();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

                        int read = socketChannel.read(buffer);
                        if (read != -1) {
                            buffer.flip();
                            storage.write(buffer);
                        }
                        else {
                            storage.close();
                            socketChannel.close();
                        }
                    }

                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я здесь использовал и мультиплексирование сетевых каналов, и асинхронные файловые каналы, чтобы показать обе возможности реализации асинхронности в NIO.2

Comment: Здравствуйте, объясните пожалуйста подробней что происходит в методе write() (то что введёться запись в файл - я понимаю, а как это работает - не ясно).

Я знаю что 

Future<Integer> writeOperaion; - объект в который можно возвратить результат ассинхронного выполнения.

и зачем мы когда записываем файл присваеваем это значение в writeOperation ? (в методе write)

Comment: Проверяется записывалось ли что-то до этого и **сколько записалось**, потом осуществляется асинхронная запись с **той позиции, на которой закончилась прошлая запись**, и `Future` представляющая результат этой записи сохраняется до следующего вызова. Если бы не сохраняли `writeOperaion`, то нам неоткуда было бы узнать сколько уже записано в файл и куда записывать новые данные.

Comment: Спасибо, это я понял. Но вопрос на счет времени в get 
`writeOperation.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` 
Ожидает, если необходимо, чтобы в течение не более указанного времени для завершения вычисления, а затем извлекает его результат, если он доступен. , зачем мы ждем 5 секунд если мы передаем по килобайту ?

`**int read = socketChannel.read(buffer);**
if (read != -1) { 
buffer.flip();
storage.write(buffer);
                        }
                        else {
                            storage.close();
                            socketChannel.close();
                        }`

Comment: Всегда при вызове блокирующихся операций надо указывать таймаут. Если по какой-то причине запись не завершится через 5 секунд, программа не повиснет, а просто закроет проблемный канал и продолжит выполнять другие операции. То есть это просто страховка. По-хорошему стоит ещё добавить дополнительную проверку для закрытия соответствующего сетевого канала, но я не стал усложнять пример.

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо =)