# Асинхронность (считывание и передача файла)

Tags: java, асинхронность, nio2

[Код в конце страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814510/2%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-nio-2), есть принятие файла, попытался написать передачу но что-то не выходит.

```
if (key.isWritable()){
     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
     SocketChannel channelRead = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
     Storage storage = (Storage) key.attachment();

     int fileSize = (int) storage.fileChannel.size();
     storage.fileChannel.read(buffer,0);
     int position = 0;

     if (fileSize != -1){
        buffer.flip();
        storage.read(buffer, channelRead);
     }
}
public void read (ByteBuffer buffer, SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        try {
            if (readOperation != null)
                positionRead += readOperation.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            fileChannel.read(buffer,positionRead);
            socketChannel.write(buffer);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException  | IOException e) {
            close();
            System.out.println("Read timeout");
        }
    }
```

Проблема в строке `socketChannel.write(buffer);` Я не могу передать файл частями. Есть несколько варинтов передачи, в 2х из 3х вариантов нужно передавать массив байт. Как в этом примере можно передавать файл частями?

Comment: У вас тут много странного. Во-первых, вы зачем-то пытаетесь считать 256 байт из начала файла каждый раз, когда сетевой канал становится доступным для записи. Во-вторых, на сколько я понимаю, `fileChannel` асинхронный, а значит `socketChannel.write(buffer)` будет вызван до того, как закончится выполнение `fileChannel.read(buffer,positionRead)`.

Comment: Я попытался поменять код учитывая ваши наставления. Для лучшей читабельности кода сохранил его на github 
(https://gist.github.com/Akalit/4e1f20d297d8ca1cf836ef56d99e830d)

но там приходиться использовать цыкл, и это не похоже на ваш пример с `if (key.isReadable())`

и на счёт `socketChannel` в него можно записать только весь файл, а для других вариантов записи нужен массив байт

Comment: Нет, асинхронная запись принципиально ничем не отличается от чтения. С запись в `SocketChannel` верно, нужен массив байт или `ByteBuffer`, но в вашем коде в момент вызова `write` в `buffer` ещё ничего нет, так как `read` свою работу не закончил.

Comment: При каком условии вызываеться ` if (key.isWritable())` ?
Код немного переделал, и при попытке соединения сервера и клиента это - >  ` if (key.isWritable())` условие не вызываеться. 
Вот новый код.
server - > https://gist.github.com/Akalit/e04fc980099770a44c1e51796abf885a
client - > https://gist.github.com/Akalit/11e06eca099b64a266bd0eddd1b0f55c

Comment: Я понимаю что условие примерно такое : если канал готов к записи.
Но я не понимаю почему он не активин при подключении клиента, хотя isAccept клиента пускает

Comment: Потому что события наступают не одновременно. Сначала клиент соединяется с сервером, канал становится acceptable. Если клиент вызывает read со своей стороны, на стороне сервера канал становится writable. Если клиент вызывает write, канал становится readable.

Comment: Здравствуйте, большое спасибо, все получилось, остались небольшие нюансы.
1) В вашем примере с read, буфер забирал байты из канала,(не просто считывал а именно забирал), а в конце он подстраивался под остаток байт в канале. И мне не хватает этой гибкости в `AsynchronousFileChannel`. чем можно это заменить?
2) получилось решить проблему изменив `socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ,new Storage());` - > `socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE,new Storage());` по отдельности в се работает,как их соеденить, что бы сервер мог одновременно и принимать и отправлять?

Comment: Вы можете "подписать" селектор на оба состояния канала: `socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, new Storage());`

Comment: Точно, можно же так перечислять.
А на счет этого подска жите ?
В вашем примере с read, буфер забирал байты из канала,(не просто считывал а именно забирал), а в конце он подстраивался под остаток байт в канале. И мне не хватает этой гибкости в AsynchronousFileChannel. чем можно это заменить?

Comment: Как я уже писал, принципиальных различий у записи и чтения нет. Достаточно использовать метод `SocketChannel.write()` вместо `read` и `AsynchronousFileChannel.read()` вместо `write`.

Comment: Возможно вы говорите о том что я уже сделал, гляньте пожалуйста код, я в комментариях все написал. https://gist.github.com/Akalit/3030891f2c79f560408cc71d6d19202e